# Do Linux pipe read/writes ALWAYS cause a context switch?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, multiprocessing, ipc

Are there still context switches to the kernel if both ends of a Linux pipe are handled by the same process? I suspect "yes", but I would like a definitive answer. BSD would have been "yes", I believe.

Adding to these suspicions, there would be at least one switch to the kernel for locking operations inside the pipe.

*This would be for the special case software installations, such as "# child procs = 0", so that the parent reads and writes both ends, etc. In this case, *fork* would be replaced with a thread runner. Assume complete object model thread safety.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there would be at least one switch to the kernel, but this is merely a privilege change (achieved via syscall) and not a context switch.

Comment: Oh that's awesome. Thanks!